# How to use the Plugin.Storereview for requesting reviews on Appstore in Xamarin forms Application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am a beginner in Xamarin forms. I have installed the plugin

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/StoreReviewPlugin

I haven't found any usage documents on how to initialize/ how to do the setup for using the plugin when i looked on the web.

How can I display the prompt to the user using this plugin?

Comment: The README doesn't mention any setup, so I assume there isn't any.  To request a review, see the docs: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/StoreReviewPlugin#request-review

Comment: In order to set it up, just right click on the solution-> manage nuget packages-> search for that library-> install it in your projects. It’s the same set up for any other nuget package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Store Review Nuget plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.StoreReview/) has been updated to v3 recently thanks to the new (August 2020) Android native Play Core library so that it displays an In-App Review on both iOS & Android:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-in-app-reviews/

So now, initializing and setup is a lot easier and you don't need to pass the `appid` anywhere, it will be shown directly in the app

Answer (score 2):

I just did a test and you do not need any additional steps to use this plugin.

Install this plugin through manage nuget packages and the in your project:

Use the namespace:

```
using Plugin.StoreReview;
```

Use the method:

```
CrossStoreReview.Current.OpenStoreListing("appid");
```

You need to test with a real device instead of a simulator.